# Send Wake on lan from magic packet

Tags: networking

Good morning to all

How can I can I send Wake on lan magic packet from Heimdall application launcher?

Thank you

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Please tell us what research you have done and what you've tried. We are not a free development service, and we expect good questions to include the research and attempts and their outcomes in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Heimdall is a web application for providing a listing of other web applications for users; using wake-on-lan (or indeed anything to do with operationally managing the linked web applications themselves) is beyond the scope of Heimdall, other than of course if you already have another web application that does that you can add a link to it to Heimdall.